# Javascript - StartOffset ignoring html markup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some proof of concept code to grab whatever text is highlighted and wrap it in a span. If someone selects text already wrapped in a span, I want to wrap that span inside as well. This works fine except for a second attempt to wrap the span later in the div because the start offset ignores all the inserted HTML markup. Is there any way to make this work? Cant use indexOf because the possibilities of the same word exists.

```
$(function () {
    $('#highlightSelectLnk').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var startOffset = 0;
        var html = "";
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                var container = document.createElement("div");
                startOffset = sel.getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
                for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                    container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
                }
                html = container.innerHTML;
            }
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
            if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
                html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
            }
        }

        var text = $('#editableContent').html();
        var replacedText = text.substring(0, startOffset) +
            '<span class="highlightedText">' + html + '</span>' + text.substring(startOffset + html.length, text.length);
        $('#editableContent').html(replacedText);

    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/df7nk7Lu/2/

Comment: Is the final goal just to color the highlighted items red?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek No. This is just POC for eventually wrapping text in spans with data attributes where the html will be passed back to a backend process to be parsed.